# How to identify the first indices of a windows of increased values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large data frame where values will suddenly spike and stay elevated (on average) for about a minute.  Lets say our window is 6 measurements long.

```
   val
0,  5
1,  3
2,  4
3,  2
4,  1200
5,  1300
6,  1200
7,  3
8,  1100
9,  1500
10, 2
11, 3
```

In this case, index 4 is where the window of increased values occurs.  Note at index 7, the value is < 1000 but is considered part of the window as the window average is still > 1000.  In my real data this one minute window is 30,720 values long.  Below is what I've coded up but it's very slow as it's iterative

```
starts = list()
last = -(512+1)*60 # ensures that the first iteration can catch the start of a window
for idx, (ts, val) in temp.reset_index().iterrows():
    if val > 0:
        if last + 512*60 < idx:
            starts.append(idx)
        last = idx
```

(the reset_index is just there so I can cache the timestamp somewhere along with the index)

Comment: What is your goal eventually, what is your expected output?

Comment: The indices of where the window(s) start.